# Python: edit matrix row in parallel

Tags: python, matrix, multiprocessing, row

here is my problem:
I would like to define an array of persons and change the entries of this array in a for loop. Since I also would like to see the asymptotics of the resulting distribution, I want to repeat this simulation quiet a lot, thus I'm using a matrix to store the several array in each row. I know how to do this with two for loops:

```
import random
import numpy as np

nobs = 100
rep = 10**2
steps = 10**2
dmoney = 1
state = np.matrix([[10] * nobs] * rep)
for i in range(steps):
    for j in range(rep)
        sample = random.sample(range(state.shape[1]),2)
        state[j,sample[0]] = state[j,sample[0]] + dmoney
        state[j,sample[1]] = state[j,sample[1]] - dmoney
```

I thought I use the multiprocessing library but I don't know how to do it, because in my simple mind, the workers manipulate the same global matrix in parallel, which I read is not a good idea.
So, how can I do this, to speed up calculations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get your point exactly, sorry. Should one thread always modify just one column / row or every data?

Comment: It's not clear what your i loop is doing as you don't ref i (presumably you use it in some unshown code to do with your simulation, distribution calcs.) However I think you could do all of your j loop in one numpy statement.. But I haven't really thought that through (np.random.choice does a similar job to python.random.sample)

Comment: I would like to edit the matrix row by row until the whole matrix is changed and repeat this step several times.

What I did not post was the function for the sample generation and an averaging step. The former is an argument against the np.random.choice and the latter an argument for editing row by row until the whole matrix has changed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this might not be much use, I haven't profiled it to see if there's a speed-up, but list comprehensions will be a little faster than normal loops anyway.

```
...
y_ix = np.arange(rep) # create once as same for each loop
for i in range(steps):
    # presumably the two locations in the population to swap need refreshing each loop
    x_ix = np.array([np.random.choice(nobs, 2) for j in range(rep)])
    state[y_ix, x_ix[:,0]] += dmoney
    state[y_ix, x_ix[:,1]] -= dmoney
```

PS what numpy splits over multiple processors depends on what libraries have been included when compiled (BLAS etc). You will be able to find info on line about this.

EDIT I can confirm, after comparing the original with the numpy indexed version above, that the original method is faster!